# jquery display correct table Sequence

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, html-table

[image]

I am facing an issue in javascript, I want to display a column `Success/Fail` in table but they shows two columns in table.. they don't show the correct value in `Success/Fail` column.

What should i do? Anyone help me?

```js
        var responseList = [{
            "summary": {
                "template_name": "test",
                "success": "2",
                "fail": "1",
            },
            "summary": {
                "template_name": "test",
                "success": "3",
                "fail": "2",
            },

        }];


        var table = document.querySelector('#my-table');
        var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
        table.appendChild(tbody);


        for (var i = 0; i < responseList.length; i++) {

            var tr = tbody.insertRow();

            var summary = responseList[i]["summary"];
            console.log(summary);
            for (var key in summary) {
                if (summary.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    console.log(key + " -> " + summary[key]);
                    var td = tr.insertCell();
                    td.innerHTML = summary[key];
                      if(key == "success" || key == "fail"){
                      // console.log("success",summary[key]);
                      // console.log("fail",summary[key]);
                      var td = tr.insertCell();
                      td.innerHTML = `${summary[key]} Successful / ${summary[key]} Failed`;
                      }

                }
            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>

</head>

<body>
    <table id="my-table" border="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Template name</th>
                <th>Success</th>
                <th>Success/Fail</th>
                <th>Fail</th>
                <th>Success/Fail</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>


    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What you want to achieve is not clear in your query. Add desired output instead.

Comment: ok i will share expected output [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12937627/sandeep-modak)

Comment: i add a photo expected output . you can check it [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12937627/sandeep-modak)

Comment: can you understand desired output? [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12937627/sandeep-modak)

Comment: desired op headings are not matching with the table headings you have mentioned in query html

Comment: can you correct my code ? [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12937627/sandeep-modak)

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is a little complex for what it needs to do, there isn't much value iterating over the keys of the summary object in a loop to build the table. It's much simpler to access the keys directly as i've done below.

```js
var responseList = [
    {
        "template_name": "test",
        "success": "2",
        "fail": "1",
    },
    {
        "template_name": "test",
        "success": "3",
        "fail": "2",
    },
];

var table = document.querySelector('#my-table');
var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
table.appendChild(tbody);

responseList.forEach(summary => {
  var tr = tbody.insertRow();
  tr.insertCell().innerHTML = `${summary.template_name}`
  tr.insertCell().innerHTML = `${summary.success}`
  tr.insertCell().innerHTML = `${summary.fail}`
  tr.insertCell().innerHTML = `${summary.success}/${summary.fail}`
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>

</head>

<body>
    <table id="my-table" border="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Template Name</th>
                <th>Success</th>
                <th>Fail</th>                
                <th>Success/Fail</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>


    </table>
</body>

</html>
```